# cleaning list in python

Tags: python, list

I have several list they have `2` values - one or more words and score,   `[(deployment appears', 4.0), ('times bigger', 4.0), ('data forced', 4.0), ('washington media', 4.0), ('barely understood', 4.0), ('american public', 4.0), ('country', 4.0), ('house', 4.0)]`

How can I create a list that has only words - for example, `[('deployment appears'), ('times bigger'), ('data forced'), ('washington media'), ('barely understood'), ('american public'), ('accurate accounting'), ('white house')]`

Comment: Why would you want this: `('data forced')`? Is not `'data forced'` sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [('deployment appears', 4.0), ('times bigger', 4.0), ('data forced', 4.0), ('washington media', 4.0), ('barely understood', 4.0), ('american public', 4.0), ('country', 4.0), ('house', 4.0)]
new_s = [i[:1] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[('deployment appears',), ('times bigger',), ('data forced',), ('washington media',), ('barely understood',), ('american public',), ('country',), ('house',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions to the rescue:

```
result = [x[0] for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
your_list = [('deployment appears', 4.0), ...]
filtered = [tuple(some_number) for _, some_number in your_list]
```